# Get row by index SugarORM

Tags: android, sugarorm

Is is possible to get value from sugarORM database by index ? I can't find this in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [reo](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar), there is a line where they use findById to get a value by its index. Like so:

```
Book book = Book.findById(Book.class, 1);
```

Unfortunately Indexes are not natively supported by the library as you can see in this [issue](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar/issues/159). You can't create Indexes for columns natively actually. You can do as one of the users said in the issue and create the index for  a certain column using migrations, but that's a bit hacky I:/

Comment: it is ID not index, sometimes if you delete all data in db and add again something, you have 1 value with ID for example 5 on index 1